# What kind of locally symmetric space is a rational sphere

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, lattices, symmetric-spaces

Using Dehn Surgery, we can construct compact hyperbolic $3$-manifolds with vanishing Betti numbers $b_1=b_2=0$, i.e., a rational homology $3$-sphere.

My question is the following.

Is there other odd dimensional compact locally symmetric space $\Gamma\backslash G/K$ of non-compact type which is also a rational homology sphere?

I add "odd dimension", since the Euler characteristic number of an even dimensional rational homology sphere is $2$ which is too strong restriction.

Remark also that, if $G$ is simple with real rank $\mathrm{rk}_\mathbf{R}(G)\ge 2$, for any uniform lattice $\Gamma\subset G$, we have $b_1=0$. But, I have non idea how about $b_2,b_3,...$

Comment: Note that the only irreducible symmetric spaces of noncompact type that have odd dimension are those associated to the groups $\mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbf{R})$ with $n\ge 3$, $n=0,3$ modulo 4, to $\mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbf{H})$ for even $n\ge 2$, or $\mathrm{SO}(p,q)$ with odd $p\le q$, $p+q\ge 8$, or to a complex simple group of odd complex dimension, namely $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbf{C})$ for even $n\ge 2$, $\mathrm{SO}_n(\mathbf{C})$ for $n\ge 7$, $n=2,3$ modulo 4, $\mathrm{Sp}(2n,\mathbf{C})$, $n\ge 3$ odd, and $E_7(\mathbf{C})$.

Comment: Closed flat manifolds that are rational homology spheres exist in all odd dimensions, see [A. Szczepański, Aspherical manifolds with the Q-homology of a sphere. Mathematika 30 (1983), no. 2, 291–294 (1984)]  They generalize the classical Hantzche-Wendt flat 3-manifold. I am not aware of any other locally symmetric (higher-dimensional) examples, and in fact, in higher dimensions it is not easy to construct aspherical manifolds that are rational homology spheres.

Comment: Already in dimension 5 there are 3 types of symmetric spaces of non-compact type, corresponding to the groups $\mathrm{SO}(5,1)$ (rank 1); $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{R})\times\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{C})$ and $\mathrm{SL}_3(\mathbf{R})$ (rank 2). Can we discard any of these types?

Comment: I would tend to believe that $b_2=0$ for every higher-rank lattice, provided the ambient semisimple Lie group has finite $\pi_1$. If so, this would imply that any compact oriented locally symmetric space based on $\mathrm{SL}_3(\mathbf{R})$ (and hence 5-dimensional) is a rational homology sphere.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. @YCor, I am very interested to the  $\mathrm{SL}_3(\mathbf{R})$ case. How does $b_2$ relate to the $\pi_1$ of the ambient semisimple group?

Comment: Say $G$ is simple. If $G$ has infinite $\pi_1$, then one gets a central extension by $Z$, which usually (I guess, always except when $G=SL_2(R)$ and $\Gamma$ is non-cocompact) remains nontrivial on $\Gamma$, and thus $b_2(G/\Gamma)\ge 1$, at least when $\Gamma$ is contained in the connected component of $G$. (This probably discards the case $SL_2(R)\times SL_2(C)$ but I can't exclude the existence of a torsion-free lattice in $PGL_2(R)\times PGL_2(C)$, orientation-preserving but whose projection on $PGL_2(C)$ is not orientation-preserving, with both $b_1=b_2=0$.)

Comment: Conversely, when $G$ has finite $\pi_1$, then the continuous group cohomology of $G$ vanishes in degree 2. One could hope, possibly under further hypotheses to deduce the vanishing of $H^2(\Gamma,\mathbf{R})$. There are results of this kind by Matsushima, the book of Borel-Wallach (hard to read for me), but I haven't be able to detect anything applying to the vanishing of $b_2$ of lattices in $SL_3(\mathbf{R})$.

Comment: @YCor: I think results of Matsushima, Borel, et el gives cohomology vanishing in dimensions $<[n/2]$ where $n$ is the rank, so this is not enough for $SL_3(\mathbf{R})$. People (e.g. Nicolas Bergeron) have been working on such matters extensively so perhaps it is easier to ask the experts.

Comment: Correction: the vanishing is in positive dimensions $<n$ where $n$ is the rank. For $SL_3(\mathbf{R})$ it shows that $H^1=0$. See 2.6 in https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/27e1/ca72f981bbb42bdb2552dce20a53a4a82be5.pdf.

Comment: "the Euler characteristic number of an even dimensional rational homology sphere is 2 which is too strong restriction" this changes the way to look at the problem (it becomes related to minimal volume) but I'm not sure it is known in general that locally symmetric spaces with positive Euler characteristic can't be homology spheres.

Comment: Follow-up question concerning specifically the case of $\mathrm{SL}_3(\mathbf{R})$.

Answer (score 4):

This question came up in a recent research we hold with Lubotzky, Sauer and Weinberger. We came across this post while looking online for its solution. I will share our findings.

**O (Original question):** Which compact locally symmetric spaces are odd dimensional rational homology spheres?

**PO (Partial answer to O):** For a semisimple Lie group $G$, a maximal compact subgroup $K<G$ and a cocompact lattice $\Gamma<G$, $\Gamma\backslash G/K$ is an odd dimensional rational homology sphere only if $G$ is locally isomorphic to $\text{SO}(n,1)$, with the single possible exception $G=\text{SL}_3(\mathbb{R})$.

Erasing the word "locally" in **O**, we get the following.

**R (Related question):** Which compact symmetric spaces are odd dimensional rational homology spheres?

For this we actually have a full solution.

**FR (Full answer to R):** A compact group $U$ and a closed subgroup $K<U$ give rise to a symmetric space $U/K$ which is an odd dimensional rational homology sphere iff (up to center) either $U=\text{SU}(3)$ and $K=\text{SO}(3)$ or $U=\text{SO}(n+1)$ and $K=\text{SO}(n)$ ($n$ even).

Note that the only case which is not an actual a sphere is $\text{SU}(3)/\text{SO}(3)$, which is the dual symmetric space of $G=\text{SL}_3(\mathbb{R})$.
In this case, $\Gamma\backslash G/K$ is **not** an odd dimensional rational homology sphere at least for some cocompact lattice $\Gamma<G$ by the beautiful discussion [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/313917/second-betti-number-of-lattices-in-mathrmsl-3-mathbfr?noredirect=1&lq=1).

---

**Proof of FR:**

[1, Theorem 1] gives that (up to center) either $U=\text{SU}(3)$ and $K=\text{SO}(3)$ or $U/K$ is an actual odd dimensional sphere.
In [2]* there is a classification of all presentations of odd dimensional spheres as a homogeneous spaces, that is a compact Lie groups mod a closed subgroup. Comparison with the [table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_space) of compact symmetric spaces and inspection reveals that the only pairs in the classification which give rise to symmetric spaces are $\text{SO}(n)<\text{SO}(n+1)$ for $n$ even.

$*$ I couldn't find the actual reference [2], but the result is described in the MatchSciNet review, as well as in [3, p. 179].

---

**Proof of FR $\Rightarrow$ PO**:

Let $U/K$ be dual symmetric space of $G/K$.
Denoting by $H^n_{\text{cg}}$ the continuous group cohomology and by unlabeled $H^n$ the space cohomology, we have $H^n_{\text{cg}}(G,\mathbb{C}) \cong H^n(U/K,\mathbb{C})$ and Shapiro Lemma gives
$$H^n(\Gamma\backslash G/K,\mathbb{C})\cong H^n_{\text{cg}}(\Gamma,\mathbb{C})\cong H^n_{\text{cg}}(G,L^2(G/\Gamma)) \cong H^n_{\text{cg}}(G,\mathbb{C})\oplus H^n_{\text{cg}}(G,L^2_0(G/\Gamma)).$$
Therefore we get an injection $H^n(U/K,\mathbb{C}) \hookrightarrow H^n(\Gamma\backslash G/K,\mathbb{C})$.

We thus get a necessary condition: If $\Gamma\backslash G/K$ is a rational cohomology sphere than so is the dual symmetric space of $G$ (note that this condition does not depends on $\Gamma$).

We are done by using **FR** and noting that $\text{SU}(3)/\text{SO}(3)$ is the compact dual of $\text{SL}_3(\mathbb{R})/\text{SO}(3)$ and $\text{SO}(n+1)/\text{SO}(n)$ is the compact dual of $\text{SO}(n,1)/\text{SO}(n)$.

---

[1] Wolf, Joseph,
Symmetric spaces which are real cohomology spheres.
J. Differential Geometry 3 (1969), 59–68.

[2] Borel, Armand
Le plan projectif des octaves et les sphères comme espaces homogènes. (French)
C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris 230 (1950), 1378–1380.

[3] Besse, Arthur L.
Einstein manifolds.
Ergebnisse der Mathematik und ihrer Grenzgebiete (3) [Results in Mathematics and Related Areas (3)], 10. Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 1987.

Comment: Borel's paper: https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k3182n/f1378.item